# adding more logic in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

my Input XML File

```
<employerinfo id="2242">
<Employer>
 <Employeedetail>Sam SR Engineer 10%</Employeedetail>
 <Employeedetail>Sam SR 26%</Employeedetail>
 <Employeedetail>Sam SR</Employeedetail>
<Employeedetail>Sam GRTE</Employeedetail>
</Employer >
</employerinfo>
```

Expected Output file

```
<Employer>
<Employeedetails>
 <Employeedetail1>
  <Employeedetail>
   <Name>Sam</Name>
   <Grade>SR Engineer</Grade>
   <Experience>10</Experience>
  </Employeedetail>
  <Employeedetail>
   <Name>Sam</Name>
   <Grade>SR</Grade>
   <Experience>26</Experience>
 <Employeedetail>
   <Name>Sam</Name>
   <Grade>SR</Grade>
   <Experience>10</Experience>
</Employeedetail>
 <Employeedetail>
   <Name>Sam</Name>
   <Grade>GRTE</Grade>
   <Experience>10</Experience>
</Employeedetail >
</Employeedetail1>
</Employeedetails>
</Employer>
```

I tried searching in Google for this type of XML how to do in xslt 1.0 & xslt 2.0

Several other Stack Overflow user also helped me. But still this is the final detail input  XML.

If i added extra parent node in XML and if i modified in XSLT i am not getting the value

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: thats very difficult because the Employer detail does not have consistent spaces. i.e. "Sam SR Engineer 10%" vs "Sam SR 26%". Is the name always one word?

Comment: The input XML is totally unsuitable for the desired output since it does not contain the information that any XSLT logic would expect in order to achieve the output. For example, the input makes no indication that, apparently, "SR Engineer" relates to grade. Any transformation like this would have to be very hard-coded since there is little opportunity for dynamism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution so far:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'
    version='1.0'
    >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Employer">
<Employer>
<Employeedetails>
<Employeedetail1>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Employeedetail"/>
</Employeedetail1>
</Employeedetails>
</Employer>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Employeedetail">
<Employeedetail>
<xsl:variable name="s1" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
<xsl:variable name="name" select="substring-before($s1,' ')"/>
<Name><xsl:value-of select="$name"/></Name>

<xsl:variable name="s2" select="substring-after($s1,' ')"/>
<xsl:call-template name="t">
    <xsl:with-param name="s" select="$s2"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="grade"></xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="exp"></xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
</Employeedetail>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="t">
<xsl:param name="s"/>
<xsl:param name="grade"/>
<xsl:param name="exp"/>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="contains($s,' ')">
        <xsl:call-template name="t">
            <xsl:with-param name="s" select="substring-after($s,' ')"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="grade"><xsl:value-of select="$grade"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text><xsl:value-of  select="substring-before($s,' ')"/></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="exp"><xsl:value-of  select="substring-after($s,' ')"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when  test="string-length($exp)&gt;0">
                <Grade><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($grade)"/></Grade>
                <Experience><xsl:value-of select="$exp"/></Experience>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Grade><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($s)"/></Grade>
                <Experience>10</Experience>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<Employer>
  <Employeedetails>
    <Employeedetail1>
      <Employeedetail>
        <Name>Sam</Name>
        <Grade>SR Engineer</Grade>
        <Experience>10%</Experience>
      </Employeedetail>
      <Employeedetail>
        <Name>Sam</Name>
        <Grade>SR</Grade>
        <Experience>26%</Experience>
      </Employeedetail>
      <Employeedetail>
        <Name>Sam</Name>
        <Grade>SR</Grade>
        <Experience>10</Experience>
      </Employeedetail>
      <Employeedetail>
        <Name>Sam</Name>
        <Grade>GRTE</Grade>
        <Experience>10</Experience>
      </Employeedetail>
    </Employeedetail1>
  </Employeedetails>
</Employer>
```

Comment: Hi @pierre thanks for your output there is a single step missing from my side itself i don't want the % in the output could you pls help me out there

Comment: use the xpath function translate:  select="translate($exp,'%','')"

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Employer">
 <Employer>
  <Employeedetails>
   <Employeedetail1>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </Employeedetail1>
  </Employeedetails>
 </Employer>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employeedetail">
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="^(.*) ((SR|GR).*?)( ([0-9]+)%)?$">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
   <Employeedetail>
    <Name><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"/></Name>
    <Grade><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></Grade>
    <Experience><xsl:value-of select="if(regex-group(5)) then regex-group(5) else 10"/></Experience>
   </Employeedetail>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
 </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you all people who helped me for the above question

Comment: Hi all how to use XSLT 2.0 in tomcat can anyone help me here